# Extract lines corresponding to the minimum value in the last column

Tags: awk

I need help with extracting all the lines from the file that has minimum number in the last column, i.e 7 in in this case.

The sample file is as below:

File-1.txt

```
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111] 7
VALID_PATH :  [102, 81, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111] 7
VALID_PATH :  [102, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111] 7
VALID_PATH :  [102, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111]  7
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111] 8
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111]  8
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 109, 23, 125, 110, 111]    8
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 6, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111] 9
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 88, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111]    9
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 110, 111]    9
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 110, 111] 9
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 6, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111] 10
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 6, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111]  10
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 6, 112, 109, 23, 125, 110, 111]    10
```

Here, I want to extract all the lines that have 7, which is the least value (minimum value) in the last column and save the output into another file File-2.txt by only extracting the values enclosed in [], as shown below.

File-2.txt

```
102, 80, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111
102, 81, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111
102, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111
102, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111
```

I could use awk to get the least value as "7" from the last column using the code as below:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline;min=max=$NF}
NF{
    max=(max>$NF)?max:$NF
    min=(min>$NF)?$NF:min
}
END{print min,max}' File-1.txt
```

and to print only the values in square brackets [] buy using the awk code as below:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' RS='[' FS=']' File-1.txt
```

but, I am stuck in assigning the least value obtained from first awk script, i.e. 7 in this case to extract the corresponding numbers enclosed in [], as shown in File-2.txt.

Any help in resolving this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Asha:@try:

```
awk '{Q=$NF;gsub(/.*\[|\]/,"");$NF="";A[Q]=A[Q]?A[Q] ORS $0:$0;MIN=MIN<Q?(MIN?MIN:Q):Q} END{print A[MIN]}' Input_file
```

Will add description shortly too.

**EDIT:** Following is the description on same too.

```
awk '{
Q=$NF;                    ##### Making last field of Input_file as NULL.
gsub(/.*\[|\]/,"");       ##### Using global substitution functionality of awk to remove everything till [ and then remove ] from the line as per your required output.
$NF="";                   ##### Nullifying the last column of each line as you don't need them in your output.
A[Q]=A[Q]?A[Q] ORS $0:$0; ##### creating an array named A whose index is Q variable(whose value is already assigned previously to last column), creating array A with index Q and concatenating it's value in itself.
MIN=MIN<Q?(MIN?MIN:Q):Q}  ##### Creating a variable named MIN(to get the minimum last value of each line) and comparing it's value to each line's last field and keeping the minimum value in it as per requirement.
END{print A[MIN]}         ##### In end block of code printing the value of array A whose index is variable MIN to print all the lines whose index is variable named MIN.
' Input_file              ##### Mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! A short description od the code will be of great help in understanding the code. Also, I would appreciate it very much if you can use my codes to extract the lines. This will help me in understanding how the output from code can be a input into the other.

Answer (score 2):

Reading same file twice, instead of using `array` practically bit slower, as we read file 2 times, but zero memory overhead.

```
awk -F'[][]' 'FNR==NR{if(min > $NF || min==""){ min=$NF} next }
     $NF==min{ print $2 }' file file
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F'[][]' 'FNR==NR{                           # This block we read file 
                                                 # and will find whats minimum                                                 
             if(min > $NF || min==""){ 
                min=$NF                          # NF gives no of fields, assign the value of $NF to variable min 
             } 
              next 
     }
     $NF==min{                                   # Here we read file 2nd time, if last field value is equal to minimum
              print $2 
     }' file file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111] 7
VALID_PATH :  [102, 81, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111] 7
VALID_PATH :  [102, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111] 7
VALID_PATH :  [102, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111]  7
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111] 8
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111]  8
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 109, 23, 125, 110, 111]    8
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 6, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111] 9
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 88, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111]    9
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 110, 111]    9
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 110, 111] 9
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 6, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111] 10
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 6, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111]  10
VALID_PATH :  [102, 80, 127, 6, 112, 109, 23, 125, 110, 111]    10
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'[][]' 'FNR==NR{ if(min > $NF || min==""){ min=$NF } next }
       $NF==min{ print $2 }' file file
102, 80, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111
102, 81, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111
102, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111
102, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sort` as a *helper* to get a *neat* code:

```
$ sort -t\] -nk 2 your_file |awk '$NF!=L && L{exit}{L=$NF;print $2}' FS='[][]'
102, 112, 37, 109, 23, 125, 111
102, 112, 37, 56, 23, 125, 111
102, 80, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111
102, 81, 112, 109, 23, 125, 111
```

Answer (score 2):

read once (ex: for streaming/piped info) with minimum memory use

```
awk -F'[][]' '
   # init counter
   NR == 1 { m = $3 + 1 }

   # add or replace content into the buffer if counter is lower or equal
   $3 <= m { b = ( $3 == m ? b "\n" : "" ) $2; m = $3 }

   # at the end, print buffer
   END { print b }
   ' YourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[][]' -vmin=99999 '$NF<=min{min=$NF;print $2}'
```

1. `-F'[][]'` set FS to regexp `[][]` which mean "or [ or ]", i.e. your input string will be splited in 3 field.
2. `-vmin=99999` set variable min to `99999`. In this variable will be stored minum value of last field
3. `$NF <= min {min = $NF; print $2}` if current last field less or equal then stored in variable `min`,
   then update `min`, and output what we need.

Comment: Yes, test data was sorted.. :) But you are right. This one work with unsorted also: `awk -F'[][]' -vmin=999999 '$NF <= min{min=$NF;a[n]=a[n]""$2"\n"} END{print a[min]}'`